# opposite of selectedvalue in radio button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I'm working in ASP.net and I want to display both values C and F.

This is my default file:

```
  <asp:Label ID="RadioLabel" runat="server" Text="Typ av konvertering"/>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem value="C" Selected="true">Celcius till fahrenheit</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem value="F">Fahrenheit till celcius</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Konventera" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
```

I use `RadioButtonList.SelectedValue` in my code behind file to get the value I select.
My question is if there is any way to display the other value that I didn't select?

I'm trying to make a celcius to fahrenheit converter and reverse.

Answer (score 0):

To get all items in `RadioButtonList` you can do something like this.

```
foreach (ListItem item in RadioButtonList.Items)
{
    // write your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answear but I managed my problem with if statements

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution yourself